# Updating or adding data to an associative array as a cache

Tags: php, cache

I have this if else statement where I don't know how to remove the code duplication

```
if(array_key_exists($key,$cachetable))
{
 if($cachetable[$key] != $newdata[$key])
  {
    //data existed but is not valid
    //update the cachetable
    $cachetable[$key] == $newdata[$key]
  }
}

else
{
    //data didn't existed before in cache so add it now
    //update the cachetable
    $cachetable[$key] == $newdata[$key]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the code to this:

```
//just use the AND operator (&&) to check if it's both existing AND valid
//use strict comparison (===) whenever possible
if(array_key_exists($key,$cachetable) && $cachetable[$key] === $newdata[$key]){
    //data exists and valid
} else {
    //data doesn't exist or isn't valid
    //to assign data, use a single equal (=). 
    //A double equal (==) is a loose comparison
    $cachetable[$key] = $newdata[$key];
 }
```

---

```
//this one checks if it's not in the array
//or if it does, it checks if it's not valid
//when either one is true, the condition passes
if(!array_key_exists($key,$cachetable) || $cachetable[$key] !== $newdata[$key]){
    //data doesn't exists or isn't valid
}
```

Comment: I thought of this myself but then thought that I should check $cachetable[$key] === $newdata[$key] only after doing the array_key_exists() otherwise some error would occur. was I wrong? is it possible to check both things in one if statement?

Comment: as far as i know, if a condition fails in an AND (`&&`), PHP does not continue evaluating the rest of the conditions. therefore, `$cachetable[$key] === $newdata[$key]` is only evaluated when `array_key_exists($key,$cachetable)` returns true.

Comment: The `&&` operator is a "short circuit" operator, meaning it only evaluates the expression to the right if the one to the left evaluated to `true`.

Comment: Ok, However I don't do anything when the data is valid, so maybe you could edit the answer to have only a if with the ! appended there

Comment: @nischayn22 updated

Comment: `if( ! array_key_exists($key, $cachetable) || $cachetable[$key] !== $newdata[$key]) { }` - removes need for else statement